# PLY parser - equation assignation

Tags: python, parsing, equation, ply

I'm creating a calculator using PLY. 
I want to be able to assign equation to a dictionary as I am able to assign variables to another dictionary.

The way I'm assigning variables : `x = 10` (in the dict `x`will be the key and `10`the value)

The way I want to be able to assign equation : `fun(x) = x + 42` (in the dict `fun`will be the key and a tuple `('x', 'x+10')` will be the value).

It's working with this writing `fun|x| = x + 42` (note the 'pipe' symbol here). But it's not working with parentheses.

How can I make it work the right way ?

Here's my code so far :

```py
import ply.yacc as yacc
import ply.lex as lex

################################## LEXER ################################

tokens = (
    'NAME',
    'NUMBER',
)

t_NAME      = r'[a-zA-Z]+'
literals    = '+=-*/|()'
t_ignore    = " \t"

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

def t_error(t):
    print('Illegal character \'{}\''.format(t.value[0]))
    t.lexer.skip(1)

################################## PARSER ################################

functions = {}
variables = {}

def p_operations(p):
    """ statement : expression
    expression : fifth
    fifth : fourth
    fourth : third
    third : second
    second : first
    first : NUMBER
    """
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_plus(p):
    """ fifth : fifth '+' fourth """
    if isinstance(p[1], str) or isinstance(p[3], str):
        p[0] = str(p[1]) + p[2] + str(p[3])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] + p[3]

def p_minus(p):
    """ fifth : fifth '-' fourth """
    if isinstance(p[1], str) or isinstance(p[3], str):
        p[0] = str(p[1]) + p[2] + str(p[3])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] - p[3]

def p_implicit_times(p):
    """ fourth : fourth second """
    if isinstance(p[1], str) or isinstance(p[2], str):
        p[0] = str(p[1]) + str(p[2])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] * p[2]

def p_times(p):
    """ fourth : fourth '*' third """
    if isinstance(p[1], str) or isinstance(p[3], str):
        p[0] = str(p[1]) + p[2] + str(p[3])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] * p[3]

def p_divide(p):
    """ fourth : fourth '/' third """
    if isinstance(p[1], str) or isinstance(p[3], str):
        p[0] = str(p[1]) + p[2] + str(p[3])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] / p[3]

def p_unary_minus(p):
    """ third : '-' third """
    if isinstance(p[2], str):
        p[0] = '-' + p[2]
    else:
        p[0] = -p[2]

def p_power(p):
    """ second : first '^' third """
    if isinstance(p[1], str) or isinstance(p[3], str):
        p[0] = str(p[1]) + p[2] + str(p[3])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1] ** p[3]

def p_block(p):
    """ first : '(' expression ')' """
    p[0] = p[2]


################################ PROBLEM HERE ############################

def p_statement_assign(p):
    ''' statement : NAME '=' expression '''
    variables[p[1]] = p[3]
    p[0] = p[3]

def p_function_assign(p):
    ''' statement : NAME '|' expression '|' '=' expression '''
    functions[p[1]] = (p[3], p[6])
    p[0] = functions[p[1]]

def p_variable_expr(p):
    ''' first : NAME '''
    try : 
        p[0] = variables[p[1]]
    except:
        p[0] = p[1]

def p_error(t):
    print("Syntax error!")

################################## MAIN #################################

lexer = lex.lex() 
parser = yacc.yacc()

while True:
    try:
        question = raw_input('>>> ')
    except:
        question = input('>>> ')

    answer = parser.parse(question)
    if answer is not None:
        print(answer)
```

Comment: Please post the version of your code that doesn't work and explain how it doesn't work. If the problem is that you get a syntax error on the input `fun(x) = x + 42`, please also adjust your `p_error` function to print the location of the error and post that as well. And if PLY outputs any warnings, please post those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allow implicit multiplication. That means that `f(x)` can be parsed as a product, in which case `f` would have to be reduced to `fourth` as per the implicit multiplication rule. But if it is to be parsed as an assignment, it needs to be left as a `NAME`. That's a shift-reduce conflict, which can easily be seen in `parser.out`:

```
state 3

    (16) statement -> NAME . = expression
    (17) statement -> NAME . ( expression ) = expression
    (18) first -> NAME .

  ! shift/reduce conflict for ( resolved as shift
```

What you see here is that when the parser sees `NAME` followed by `(`, it doesn't know whether to reduce `NAME` to `first` (and subsequently to `second`, etc. up to `fourth`), in the expectation that the statement is a simple computation, or to shift the `(`, thereby committing itself to treating this as a function definition.

You might already have experienced a similar problem, since a natural grammar for function definition is:

```
statement : NAME '(' NAME ')' '=' expression
```

but you've replaced the second `NAME` with `expression`. That will avoid the shift-reduce conflict before the `)`, at the cost of accepting questionable function definitions (`f(a+3) = 2a`).

It's possible to do something similar to avoid this shift-reduce conflict (but it's a very ad hoc solution):

```
statement : fourth '(' expression ')' '=' expression
```

That "works" in the sense that it accepts correct expressions. But it also silently (or somewhat silently) accepts quite a few other expressions:

This one is fine:

```
>>> f(a) = a + 3
('a', 'a+3')
```

But these are weird:

```
>>> -f(a) = a + 3
('a', 'a+3')
>>> 3f(a) = a + 3
('a', 'a+3')
>>> 3f(a+2) = a + 3
('a+2', 'a+3')
```

Alternatively, you could ignore the shift-reduce conflict, since PLY will, by default, do the shift (as it says in `parser.out`: "resolved as shift"). That will prevent the parser from accepting the weird examples above, but it will also incorrectly parse some expressions which might seem reasonable:

These ones seem appropriate:

```
>>> f(a) = a + 3
('a', 'a+3')
>>> -f(a) = a + 3
Syntax error!
a+3
>>> 3f(a) = a + 3
Syntax error!
a+3
```

But we might expect this to print 105:

```
>>> a=7
7
>>> a(2a+1)
Syntax error!
```

If that doesn't bother you, you can stop reading now.

---

Your grammar is not ambiguous, and nor would it be ambiguous if you'd written the definition syntax with greater specificity:

```
statement : NAME '(' NAME ')' '=' expression
```

or, if you wanted to allow functions with multiple arguments:

```
statement : NAME '(' name_list ')' '=' expression
name_list : NAME
name_list : name_list ',' NAME
```

But it is not LR(1), and it will be very difficult to make it LR(1). Both of the syntaxes suggested above are LR(4), and since every LR(k) grammar can theoretically be converted mechanically into a (very bloated and hardly readable) LR(1) grammar, a solution must exist. It won't be pretty, though.

(The actual syntax you are using, with `expression`, is not LR(k) for any k, because `expression` can be arbitrarily long and the parser has to see beyond the argument list in order to decide whether or not to reduce the first `NAME`.)

Since the grammar is unambiguous, you could parse it with a GLR/GLL/Earley/etc. parser, but PLY doesn't produce those and I don't know of a Python parser generator which does (although that doesn't mean that one doesn't exist). There are various GLR parser generators available for other languages.

With PLY, though, your best bet is probably to use the general syntax shown above as an ad hoc solution and then solve the problem of accepting incorrect definitions by doing a check in the semantic action.

However, that check will be a bit tricky unless you bite the bullet and change to a parser which produces ASTs instead of doing immediate evaluation, as we have discussed several times. If the semantic values are ASTs, then it will be straight-forward to verify that both `p[1]` and `p[3]` are simple names in the action function for

```
statement : fourth '(' expression ')' '=' expression
```

I suppose, human ingenuity being limitless, that you might find some other hack which lets you do the test. But don't expect much sympathy when it fails on a corner case.

Comment: Hello @rici : about biting the bullet and switching to a parser which produce AST, would you recommend ANTLR ?

Comment: @cuzureau: I've never used ANTLR for Python. But I don't see any good reason not to use Ply. Building ASTs is really easy, and if you do it yourself, you get the AST you want. ANTLR automatically builds a concrete parse tree, which is an unnecessarily complicated view of the syntax tree.

Comment: Hey @rici, in the action function for ```statement : fourth '(' expression ')' '=' expression``` to store p[6] as an AST, how can I get it without evaluating p[6] ? Should I still concatenate str as I did : ```if isinstance(p[1], str) or isinstance(p[3], str):
        p[0] = str(p[1]) + p[2] + str(p[3])```. How can I did it differently without knowing the value of 'x' for example in ```f(x) = x * 10```? Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @cuzureau: if all of your semantic actions produce AST nodes, then `p[6]` (as well as `p[1]` and `p[3]`) is already an AST node. You just form a new AST node from those three things, which will be a function definition AST node. You will want to verify that `p[1]` and `p[3]`` are `name` nodes (to detect syntax errors), but other than that there is nothing special. The function definition node creates a scope, since whatever variable name `p[3[` represents is a bound variable in the subtree rooted at `p[6]`. It is possible but not necessary to do this analysis when you create the node.

Comment: Since all my actions have to produce AST node, why not using Lark parser or something that create AST automatically ?

Comment: @cuzureau: if the parse tree produced by Lark satisfies your needs, go for it. On the other hand, as the [Ply manual indicates](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn34), generating an AST is quite simple, and if you do it yourself you can abstract the syntax in the manner most convenient for your application.

Comment: So, let me get this straight : first I parse my string with PLY to create my AST as the manual indicates. And then, I parse again, this time the AST, to apply the action rules I want ?

Comment: @cuzureau: walking the AST is not parsing.

Comment: @cuzureau: to do any non-trivial semantic analysis, you'll need to compute both inherited and synthetic attributes. Having the entire AST available makes that a lot easier, as you will discover when you write sone actual code.